# How to upload multiple file simultaneously using ASP .Net Core 3.1 with threads

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, web-applications, video-upload

I am working on ASP .Net Core. I need to design a web page using which user can upload any video. Each video upload status must be visible to user. If user wants, user can cancel the uploading of specific video. Video upload must be independent. I am currently on information gathering stage. I show several references but nothing is useful. Can you please suggest me how can I do it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the server side I'll tell you that. All you need to do is basically `Promise.all([...filelist].map(upload))`. Your Asp.NET Core backend will inherently handle each request independently and with appropriate asynchronous IO parallelism, unless you do something silly like use synchronous APIs to write the files to disk

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you please suggest any reference regarding above mentioned comment?

Comment: Just make sure you batch Promises in your JavaScript correctly. `Promise.all` is broadly analogous .NET's `Task.WhenAll`. If you aren't familiar with either of these APIs, then you should read about asynchronous programming. Hint: IO parallelism isn't about threads, and in JavaScript you only have one thread, ever.

Comment: @AluanHaddad do you have any reference or demo?

Comment: Nope. You have to do the research